# possible of multiple sqldependancy in vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqldependency

Basically my code is based on here 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/185244-using-sqldependency-to-monitor-sql-database-changes/

Current situation is i'm having 2 table wish to monitor so i simple duplicate another similar code with first sqldependancy, but it's failed and seem like the latest sqldependancy will replace the previous sqldependancy function.

here is the code of mine

```
 Public Sub GetNames()
        If Not DoesUserHavePermission() Then
            Return
        End If


        lbQueue.Items.Clear()

        ' You must stop the dependency before starting a new one.
        ' You must start the dependency when creating a new one.
        Dim connectionString As String = GetConnectionString()
        SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString)
        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString)


        Using cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

            Using cmd As SqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand()

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PatientID FROM dbo.[patient_queue]"

                cmd.Notification = Nothing

                ' creates a new dependency for the SqlCommand
                Dim dep As SqlDependency = New SqlDependency(cmd)
                ' creates an event handler for the notification of data changes in the database
                AddHandler dep.OnChange, AddressOf dep_onchange

                cn.Open()

                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

                    While dr.Read()

                        lbQueue.Items.Add(dr.GetInt32(0))
                        doctor.lbqueue.items.add(dr.GetInt32(0))

                    End While

                End Using

            End Using

        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub dep_onchange(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlNotificationEventArgs)

        ' this event is run asynchronously so you will need to invoke to run on the UI thread(if required)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then

            lbQueue.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf GetNames))
            My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk)

        Else

            GetNames()

        End If

        ' this will remove the event handler since the dependency is only for a single notification
        Dim dep As SqlDependency = DirectCast(sender, SqlDependency)
        RemoveHandler dep.OnChange, AddressOf dep_onchange

    End Sub


    Public Sub GetMedID()
        If Not DoesUserHavePermission() Then
            Return
        End If


        lbMedQueue.Items.Clear()

        ' You must stop the dependency before starting a new one.
        ' You must start the dependency when creating a new one.
        Dim connectionString As String = GetConnectionString()
        SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString)
        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString)


        Using cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

            Using cmd As SqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand()

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT RecordID FROM dbo.[medicine_queue]"

                cmd.Notification = Nothing

                ' creates a new dependency for the SqlCommand
                Dim dep As SqlDependency = New SqlDependency(cmd)
                ' creates an event handler for the notification of data changes in the database
                AddHandler dep.OnChange, AddressOf dep_onchange2

                cn.Open()

                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

                    While dr.Read()

                        lbMedQueue.Items.Add(dr.GetInt32(0))


                    End While

                End Using

            End Using

        End Using
    End Sub


    Private Sub dep_onchange2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlNotificationEventArgs)

        ' this event is run asynchronously so you will need to invoke to run on the UI thread(if required)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then

            lbMedQueue.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf GetMedID))
            My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk)

        Else

            GetMedID()

        End If

        ' this will remove the event handler since the dependency is only for a single notification
        Dim dep As SqlDependency = DirectCast(sender, SqlDependency)
        RemoveHandler dep.OnChange, AddressOf dep_onchange2

    End Sub
```

finally i called GetNames,GetMedID on load form, it worked fine,just GetMedID is functioning and GetNames does not firing event when onchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem here is that you are calling `.Stop` and then `.Start` within each of your data access methods, thus cancelling and restarting the dependency each time you access the methods.

You just need to call `.Start` once when your application starts, and similarly `.Stop` when it ends.

For example, in a web application the best place for this is the Global.asax `Application_Start` and `Application_End` events.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right, I ran into the same issue.  A second call to SqlDependency.Start(connectionString), even after a New SqlDependency(cmd), replaced the existing, initial default Service Broker service and queue.

Service Broker creates a default Service and Queue on each Start using the a GUID as part of the Service and Queue names: Service{GUID} and Queue{GUID} - but there seems to only be one defualt Service/Queue pair available

You can verify this by putting a break-point immediately after the first Start and immediately after the second Start.  Go to SQL Server, go to your dBase and look at the 
Service Broker/Services and Service Broker/Queues folders.  You'll need to right-click on the Services and Queues folders and select refresh after the second break-point